# How to sort files of a folder numerically in a Linux distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sort

I'm currently using `Ubuntu 20.10` and I frequently use the mounted Windows partitions. One problem I'm facing now is when I open a Windows folder, I get the files (videos) in numerically unsorted manner. And there is no option in GUI to sort these files numerically.

I tried the terminal command `ls -1v 'folder_path'`, and the files get printed in a sorted manner in the terminal only, no change in the folder. What I need to do to make change in the folder? Note that, `all files are numerically indexed I have write access to the Windows folders.`

Comment: There is no examples of filenames in your question. This makes the question impossible to answer.  Also, the files are not intrinsically _stored_ in sorted order in the directory. If your GUI can't show the files in the correct order, then there is little you can do apart from renaming the files so that the GUI (whatever it is) is able to show the files in the order that you want.  There is additionally no information about what you do when you "open a Windows folder".

Answer (score 0):

First thing it that, how the list of files is displayed is completely up to the program responsible of presenting them, instead of how they are stored on the filesystem itself. If your file manager does not support the sorting feature, then there is not much that you can do.

If you are using `nautilus`, the default graphical file manager application of Ubuntu 20.10, you should be able to first click on the "toggle view" button to change the view to list from icon if not already, then click on the "name" to sort the files by name in ascending/descending order.